# sort mysql by importance and id

Tags: mysql, sorting

How can i sort first by id, than by "important". the important column is a boolean, 1 or zero

what i've tried

```
    select * from list ORDER BY `id` DESC, `important` DESC;
    select * from list ORDER BY `id` DESC, `important` DESC;
```

Comment: You have done right. There is nothing wrong in your query.

Comment: Your syntax is right. Can you please post what errors you are facing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't make sense, especically if the "ID" column is auto-increment...  it will always be in reverse order by the ID.  If you wanted all the important items FIRST, then swap your order to

```
order by
   `important` desc,
   `id` desc
```

This will put all your "important" items listed first before all not-important... Then, within all the important, will display the most recent IDs at the top working back to the oldest